# Upgrading to React navigation 5: Accessing child navigation state for a route is not safe and won't work correctly

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

In my react native app I upgraded react navigation 3 to react navigation 5.
But after upgrading when I run the application I always get this warning several times whenever I do any kind of navigation:

```
Accessing child navigation state for a route is not safe and won't work correctly
```

[image: Warning]

For example I navigate between screens of the StackNavigator using the command `this.props.navigation.push` as in the following code:

```
<Screen header={<Header
                centerComponent={
                    <CustomText style={{ color: colors.primaryText, marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15 }}>
                        {shop && shop.name}
                    </CustomText>
                }
                leftComponent={
                    <HeaderIcon
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push("SelectShop", { pop: true })}
                        type="material-community"
                        name="store" />
                }
                rightComponent={
                    <HeaderIcon
                        onPress={() => this.props.setProductLayout()}
                        image={numColumns == 1 ? GridIcon : ListIcon} />
                }
            />}>....</Screen>
```

If I click on every header icon I get this warning. These navigation commands all used to be working before upgrade. After upgrade they still work but throw this warning.
I searched through Internet and found the only place that this warning is happening:

[react-navigation/navigation-ex/packages/compat/src/createCompatNavigationProp.tsx](https://github.com/react-navigation/navigation-ex/blob/master/packages/compat/src/createCompatNavigationProp.tsx)

This is a compatibility layer that handles various API differences between React Navigation 4 and 5. I use the library because i need navigation props in some child components. But I didn't figured out why they have put the warning there! Maybe I get the warning because I'm not using typescript! If it is the case, could I ignore this warning safely?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This warning appear when you upgrade or install @react-navigation/stack or @react-navigation/native version 5.7.x.

Reverting back to:

```
"@react-navigation/compat": "5.1.28",
"@react-navigation/native": "5.6.1",
"@react-navigation/stack": "5.6.2"
```

is now also firing this warning. This warning absolutey fine btw. It's just by developer mistaken. I'm waiting for the update too for this.

Reference from this:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8348#issuecomment-657798321